Create table from Avro files in a Bucket on BigQuery with file name as a column
I have Avro files (Currents from Braze) in a bucket. I want to create or update table from these files and I need the name of the file to be a column.
For now I use this query
LOAD DATA INTO braze.email_unsubscribe
FROM FILES (
format = 'avro',
uris = ['gs://path/event_type=users.messages.email.Unsubscribe/date=2024-04-16*']);

It creates a table but I want a new column file_date with the value 2024-04-16, do you know how can I do this ? Sometimes I have more than one day to treat and the uris will look like this ['gs://path/event_type=users.messages.email.Unsubscribe/date=2024*']
